# Why am I getting footprint FPMCP server errors

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Why do I get footprint 4.8/FPMCP errors when I use iexplorer on my XP machine

Answer (score 4):

FootPrint/FPMCP (FootPrint Managed Cache Protocol) is a cache server for the website you are trying to reach. It has nothing to do with you.

Comment: you should post this as message , not as answer. thanks